# How to display selected list below select box container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, select

I am making an application where I have multi select dropdown..

In which there is a requirement that I need to place the selected items below the select container.

**Working Snippet:**

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width:100%;
}

#container > div {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

._2iA8p44d0WZ {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

._7ahQImy {
  padding: 4px 10px;
    background: #0096fb;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#search_input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">This is the main label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">secondary label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">Another label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">even more labels labels labels labels labels labels</span>
  <input type="text" class="searchBox" id="search_input" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

The above one provides the result of making the selected items and select box inside a container.

**Expected Output**

```
|------ (#container) Start -----|
|   ---------------------       |
|   | Search Input      |       |     
|   ---------------------       |
|                               |
|------ (#container) End -------|

| This is the main label |

| secondary label    |

| Another label      |

| even more labels labels labels labels labels labels |
```

**Note:**

-> **I cannot modify any of the HTML elements given.**

-> There are some dynamic classes inside it for which I cannot modify the css classes for those dynamic classes.

-> List of dynamic classes for which css properties **cannot be modified**, `_2iA8p44d0WZ` and `_7ahQImy` .

-> List of `ids/classes`, I **can modify** the css properties are `#container` and `.chip (span)`.

The exact library that I am trying to modify in my **real app** is here along with css code,

[image: Edit multiselect-react-dropdown (forked)]

Please help me to place the selected items below the `container` box as like the above given expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the internal chips of the multi-select using the `style` prop.

[CSS Customization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown#6-css-customization)

```
style={{
  chips: {
    display: 'none',
  }
}}
```

Now you need to render your `selectedValues` *outside* the `Multiselect` component. In order to do this you need to update your `state.selectedValues` state array, and map `state.selectedValues` to your own custom chip components.

1. Add an `onSelect` callback.

   ```
   onSelect={(selectedValues) => this.setState({ selectedValues })}
   ```
2. Map `state.selectedValues` to "chips". I used a span, but you can use any wrapping element and style it accordingly.

   ```
   <div>
     {selectedValues.map((chip) => (
       <span>{chip.key}</span>
     ))}
   </div>
   ```

[image]

Fullcode

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      plainArray: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"],
      objectArray: [
        { key: "Option 1", cat: "Group 1" },
        { key: "Option 2", cat: "Group 1" },
        { key: "Option 3", cat: "Group 1" },
        { key: "Option 4", cat: "Group 2" },
        { key: "Option 5", cat: "Group 2" },
        { key: "Option 6", cat: "Group 2" },
        { key: "Option 7", cat: "Group 2" }
      ],
      selectedValues: [
        { key: "Option 1", cat: "Group 1" },
        { key: "Option 2", cat: "Group 1" }
      ]
    };
    this.style = {
      chips: {
        background: "red"
      },
      searchBox: {
        border: "none",
        "border-bottom": "1px solid blue",
        "border-radius": "0px"
      },
      multiselectContainer: {
        color: "red"
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { objectArray, selectedValues } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h4 id="checkbox" className="mt40 mx20">
          <b>
            {" "}
            How can I customize the css for below below multi select to display
            only select box inside container and selected items after container
            box?{" "}
          </b>
        </h4>
        <Multiselect
          options={objectArray}
          displayValue="key"
          onSelect={(selectedValues) => this.setState({ selectedValues })}
          showCheckbox={true}
          selectedValues={selectedValues}
          style={{
            chips: {
              display: "none"
            }
          }}
        />
        <div>Some Content</div>
        <div>Some More Content</div>
        <div>
          Selected Values:
          {selectedValues.map((chip) => (
            <span>{chip.key}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-display-selected-list-below-select-box-container]

## Edit

To enable removing selected items then also implement the `onRemove` callback. To duplicate the chip style copy the applied chip CSS rules to your own style object.

```
const styles = {
  chip: {
    padding: "4px 10px",
    background: "#0096fb",
    marginRight: "5px",
    marginBottom: "5px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    display: "inline-flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    fontSize: "13px",
    color: "#fff",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  }
};
```

Also start with empty selected state

```
this.state = {
  plainArray: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"],
  objectArray: [
    { key: "Option 1", cat: "Group 1" },
    { key: "Option 2", cat: "Group 1" },
    { key: "Option 3", cat: "Group 1" },
    { key: "Option 4", cat: "Group 2" },
    { key: "Option 5", cat: "Group 2" },
    { key: "Option 6", cat: "Group 2" },
    { key: "Option 7", cat: "Group 2" }
  ],
  selectedValues: []
};

...

<Multiselect
  options={objectArray}
  displayValue="key"
  onSelect={(selectedValues) => this.setState({ selectedValues })}
  onRemove={(selectedValues) => this.setState({ selectedValues })} // <-- implement
  showCheckbox={true}
  selectedValues={selectedValues}
  style={{
    chips: {
      display: "none"
    }
  }}
/>

...

<div>
  Selected Values:
  {selectedValues.map((chip) => (
    <span key={chip.key} style={styles.chip}> // <-- set chip style prop
      {chip.key}
    </span>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Bro really thanks for your help.. And sorry that I have misssed to say one thing.. Even though the selected list of items is displayed at bottom, it needs to have same styling when it will be inside select box container.. Mainly the chip style **(blue background with close icon inside it and on click on it removing that particular item)** ..

Comment: Also the removing of items inside select box (Uncheck the checkbox) selection not  working properly bro.. Could you please kindly help me to fix both of the issue.. Other than this I don't find anything more.. Once again sorry and thanks..

Comment: @Undefined If you want to remove items then you need to also implement `onRemove`. I peeked at the DOM and CSS for `multiselect-react-dropdown`, hoping I could grab a classname, but it appears they use auto-generated classnames, so I just copied their chip CSS. I've updated the codesandbox.

Comment: Okay bro thanks, I already did the same and it works and even I have copied their css for making the close icon on each chip.. I already accepted the solution and thanks for your solution again bro..

Comment: @Undefined Great! Cheers.

Comment: Bro could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686844/how-to-handle-breadcrumbs , stuck for too long to proceed next step..