# How to handle breadcrumbs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, breadcrumbs

I am making a simple react/next js application where I am having totally three pages.

```
-> index.js

-> jobsearch.js

-> jobdescription.js
```

**Scenario:**

-> In home page there is two option for user,

> **One:** They can directly click on any job and go to job description page.

> **Two:** They can go to job search page and the by cliking on any job in search page, they can go to job description page

And finally when user reached the job description page, the **breadcrumb is shown** like,

```
  <nav className="container">
    <ol className="list-reset py-4 pl-4 rounded flex bg-grey-light text-grey">
      <li className="px-2">
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: "/"
          }}
        >
          <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">Home</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li className="px-2">
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: "/jobsearch"
          }}
        >
          <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">
            Search Page
          </a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li className="px-2"> Job - {router.query.jobId} </li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
```

And this results in displaying `Home / Job Search / JobId`.

**Requirement:**

> If navigated to job description page directly from home page then the middle
> breadcrumb (Search Page) **Should not be displayed** and the breadcrumb
> needs to be like **Home / Job - JobId**
>
> Else the breadcrumb is valid if navigated from Home to search page then to job descrition page.

**Working Snippet:**

[image: Edit Using Tailwind with Next.js (forked)]

Is there any possibility to track the previous page url while visiting job description page? As I am entirely new to this scenario, kindly please help me to achieve the result of managing breadcrumb.

Big thanks in advance..

**Edit:**

Would like to edit the question and clarify expected result bit more clear.

**Expected Result:**

**Scenario 1:**

> -> Click any job from home page, eg.., `Job -Three` (Please note here I didn't go to job search page) then it will redirected to job
> description page.
>
> -> So now the breadcrumb needs to be like `Home/ Job - Three`

---

**Scenario 2:**

> -> Click on search page link from the text in home page `Click here to go to  Search Page` and navigate to search page and click on any
> job from search page, eg.., `Job -Three` (Please note here I gone
> to job search page) then it will redirected to job description page.
>
> -> So now the breadcrumb needs to be like `Home / Job Search / Job - Three`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser maintains the history stack. I think it'd be more work than it's worth to process the stack. An easier solution may be to just send some extra route state to indicate to the description page where the user transitioned from.

jobSearch.js

Add a boolean flag state to the `Link`.

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: "/jobdescription",
    query: {
      jobId: item,
      fromSearch: true // <-- navigating from the search page
    },
  }}
>
```

jobDescription.js

Conditionally render the middle "Search Page" breadcrumb on the route state.

```
<ol className="list-reset py-4 pl-4 rounded flex bg-grey-light text-grey">
  <li className="px-2">
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: "/"
      }}
    >
      <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">Home</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
  {router.query.fromSearch && (
    <>
      <li>/</li>
      <li className="px-2">
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: "/jobsearch"
          }}
        >
          <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">
            Search Page
          </a>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  )}
  <li>/</li>
  <li className="px-2"> Job - {router.query.jobId} </li>
</ol>
```

[image: Edit how-to-handle-breadcrumbs - Using Tailwind with Next.js (forked)]

**Note:** This sends the extra "state" as part of a query string. Since Nextjs `Link` components don't support route state (like other react routing/navigation libraries) the options are to send it via the literal URL, or to temporarily store the link state in local/session storage or app state (e.g. redux). See [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/771) github issue for the request for link state.

## Edit

I found a "workaround" that allows you to send extra query parameters yet display a custom URL in the address bar. Use the optional `as` decorator. this *does* duplicate some of the work, but will at least work for users who may bookmark the URL.

```
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: "/jobdescription",
    query: {
      jobId: item,
      fromSearch: true // <-- navigating from the search page
    },
  }}
  as={`/jobDescription?jobId=${item}`}
>
```

The above linked sandbox is updated to use this fix.

Comment: Bro thanks for your help.. But it is not as expected bro..

Comment: Reason is if I go to Job search page and then if I click on any Job then the breadcrumb needs to be like, ```Home / Job Search / JobId``` but in your solution it is like ```Home / JobId``` .. So it is correct when clicking a job in home page (not going to search page) but it is wrong when we go to search page and click on any job there..

Comment: I hope you understand my requirement.. I am okay to clarify more if needed..

Comment: I have edited my question with expected result.. Please kindly check bro..

Comment: @Undefined Ah, yeah. It was working for me, then I made an edit that I thought was more optimal and I suppose I didn't quite fully reload the project. I reverted back to the working code, updated the answer and linked sandbox.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I am not supposed to pass as query string in url.. Also I don't use redux in this project.. Do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: Also let me know if you have any good solution here https://stackoverflow.com/q/65699046/13270726 .. Thanks again bro..

Comment: @Undefined Your code is already passing a query string, e.g. the job id, so the additional one didn't seem an issue. An alternative is to use session/localStorage, as suggested in the github issue I linked.

Comment: Okay bro thanks but reason for not passing down another query string is, user can copy the url and share with team so in that case it will make issue..Passing down id alone is not an issue bcoz anyhow user will share the id.. But extra query makes no sense and will make some confusion.. But Anyhow thanks for the solution bro.. ll accept it.. Kindly please check for another post bro.. (Sorry for linking you with back to back question)..

Comment: @Undefined Yeah, no worries, that was also exactly one of the reasons a request for route state was mentioned in the github issue. Seems the authors are resistant to adopting some conventions established by other routing solutions. The other solution here is cleaner with regards to the breadcrumb display itself, but would suffer the same issue for how to indicate *where* a user navigated from. I have taken a peek at your other question, but I don't have much time right now, currently. I can spend timer on it later.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation about the issue bro.. No issues bro take your own time on another question..

Comment: @Undefined Found a workaround for the URL so you can still send extra data via the query parameters. It works, albeit possibly a little "hackish", but it's the cards you're dealt with Nextjs.

Comment: Thnks for your answer bro.. It helps.. But really I am waiting for your answer for my latest question.. I am totally stuck to proceed.. I humbly request you to do the needful..

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic data to render Breadcrumbs. I just created a prototype for you.

It will work for any number of pages. You only need to pass data to `Breadcrumb` component like following

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ritchie-8y6ll

```
const breadcrumbsData = [
  {
    label: "Search",
    path: "/jobsearch",
  },
];


 // Breadcrumb.js


import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const Breadcrumbs = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="container">
      <ol className="list-reset py-4 pl-4 rounded flex bg-grey-light text-grey">
        <li className="px-2">
          <Link href="/">
            <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">Home</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>/</li>

        {data.map(({ path, label }, i) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
              <li className="px-2">
                <Link href={path}>
                  <a className="text-gray-600 no-underline text-indigo">
                    {label}
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </li>

              {data.length - 1 !== i && <li>/</li>}
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ol>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Breadcrumbs;
```

Comment: If user click any job in home page (without going to search page) then the breadcrumb needs to be like ```Home/Job Id``` whereas in your solution whatever the scenario the ```Job search``` page is displayed in middle.. In breadcrumb only we can show the pages visited by user previously from home page.. I am not even entered into Job search page and just click a job from Home page, then how can be ```Job Search``` in middle of breadcrumb can be displayed in job description page? Because I didn't go to search page at all..

Comment: I have edited my question with expected result for clarity..

Comment: I see, I will check it later and update the answer

Comment: I know, your question is already answered. I was busy with some other stuff. I also update the CodeSandbox link. It's kind of similar to Drewd-reese's answer. Thank you @Drewdreese for your answer. I also learn something new :)