# How to include html tags in text editor? [Snippet attached]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am making text editor using, [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draft-wysiwyg) and [draftjs-to-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-to-html) ..

And also I have injected the dynamic html into editor like,

**index.js:**

```
export default function App() {
  const dynamicData = `<div class="heading"> This text needs to display along with the <span> html tags </span> surrounded </div>`;

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("event ", e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ContentEditor
        name="dynamicContent"
        value={dynamicData}
        onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Current Working scenario:**

Here the things are working very well and I am able to get the plain text like,

`This text needs to display along with the html tags surrounded`

inside the editor.

**Note:** (I mean to say only text is displayed without the html tags like div, span..

**Expected:**

I am in the need to bind the entire HTML as it is inside the editor like,

```
<div class="heading"> This text needs to display along with the <span> html tags </span> surrounded </div>
```

**Working Snippet:**

[image: Edit next.js + css-only carousel (forked)]

So my **requirement** is that need to display the text inside editor as,

`<div class="heading"> This text needs to display along with the <span> html tags </span> surrounded </div>`

**instead** of

`This text needs to display along with the html tags surrounded`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript try escaping your string

Comment: hope this link will help you: https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/issues/772

Comment: I've played around with this a few times, read docs, etc... but haven't come up with any working solutions. I tested @novarx's answer and it appears to do as you request. Have you looked at HTML docs [here](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs?_k=jjqinp) (sorry, they don't have an anchor tag to the section so you'll have to search for it, it's towards the bottom of the page, second to last section).

Comment: @DrewReese, Okay bro, Thanks for your try but unfortunately the below answer also doesn't solve the purpose.. Anyhow thanks again bro..

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro do you have any idea over this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65941810/13270726 .. It occurs only on page refresh..

Comment: @Undefined That is a bit beyond my the scope of my experience. I've seen similar issues when people deploy their app onto Heroku and I think it's typically resolved with a modification to the `htaccess` file.

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro with regard to my last question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66598646/13270726  and your solution  for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610432/13270726, I have implemented header and footer to jspdf, but it is throwing error here https://codesandbox.io/s/border-not-aligned-properly-in-pdf-snippet-attached-forked-19tlq .. Could you kindly please help what I am doing wrong here??

Comment: @DrewReese, Bro.. Did you find sometime to help me out??

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by @Rod911 you can do something like this:

```js
import "../carousel.css";
import React from "react";
import ContentEditor from "../components/text_editor";

function escape(unescaped) {
  return unescaped
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}

function unescape(escaped) {
  return escaped
    .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
    .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
    .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
    .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}

export default function App() {
  const dynamicData = escape(
    `<div class="heading">This text needs to display along with the <span> html tags </span> surrounded </div>`
  );

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    console.log("event ", unescape(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ContentEditor
        name="dynamicContent"
        value={dynamicData}
        onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

May be it would be nice to use a specific Class for the content, which would simplify the convertion. May be take a look at: https://www.itsrainingmani.dev/blog/string-prototype-extension/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
export default function App() {

    function getConvertedText(text) {
        console.log(text);
        text = text.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        return text;
    }
    const dynamicData = '<div class="heading"> This text needs to display along with the ' + getConvertedText("<span> html tags </span>") + ' surrounded </div>';

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        console.log("event ", e.target.value);
    };

    return ( <
        >
        <
        ContentEditor name = "dynamicContent"
        value = {
            dynamicData
        }
        onChange = {
            (event) => handleInputChange(event)
        }
        /> <
        />
    );
}
```