# Border not aligned properly in PDF [Snippet attached]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am making a very simple react application with ver minimal of content.

**index.js:**

```
<div className="App">
  <div id="printable-div">
    <h1>Generate PDF</h1>
    <p>Create a screenshot from the page, and put it in a PDF file.</p>
    <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
      *Open this page in new window and press the button.
    </p>
  </div>
  <br />
  <button id="print" onClick={printPDF}>
    PRINT
  </button>
</div>
```

Where here the div with id `printable-div` will gets printed.

I also applied a css for this like,

```
#printable-div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

But while click on the button, the download of pdf happens whereas on opening the pdf file, the border is not aligned properly.

[image]

Also here, the order needs to be to the page but whereas it applied only to the div.

**Libraries used:**

-> [**jsPdf**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

-> [**html2canvas**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)

And the code executed on click on the print button as follows,

```
  const printPDF = () => {
    const domElement = document.getElementById("printable-div");
    html2canvas(domElement).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const pdf = new jsPdf();
      pdf.addImage(imgData, "JPEG", 0, 0);
      pdf.save(`${new Date().toISOString()}.pdf`);
    });
  };
```

**Complete working example:**

[image: Edit html2canvas-jspdf (forked)]

Can anyone humbly help me to achieve the result of making the border properly aligned to the entire page?
It is okay if the libraries used needs to be changed to other alternative..

**Requirement:**

The entire page needs to have border visible with all sides equal spacing and the content needs to be inside of the border..

[image]

Comment: my suggestion is, you need to make the layout manually using doc.rect method, you can use online editor to help your work https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codesandbox and it seems you'd already applied @Ihsan's solution, but to build on that solution I found that `jsPDF` has a `fromHMTL` function, so you can skip rendering to a canvas first.

```
const printPDF = () => {
  const domElement = document.getElementById("printable-div");
  const doc = new jsPdf();
  doc.fromHTML(domElement, 10, 5); // position within rectangle
  doc.rect(5, 5, 200, 0.3);
  doc.rect(5, 5, 0.3, 285);
  doc.rect(5, 290, 200, 0.3);
  // doc.rect(5, 30, 200, 0.3); // this is the "middle" horizontal bar
  doc.rect(205, 5, 0.3, 285);
  doc.save(`${new Date().toISOString()}.pdf`);
};
```

I commented out the middle horizontal bar as this bar's vertical position just needs to be tweaked for where you want/need it.

#### Edit

Instead of a bunch of rectangles you can draw a single rectangle and stroke it to create the outer border, and use a line to fill in the horizontal "bar". IMO this reads a little more cleanly.

```
const printPDF = () => {
  const domElement = document.getElementById("printable-div");
  const doc = new jsPdf();

  // Create border
  doc.rect(5, 5, 200, 285, "S").line(5, 45, 205, 45, "S");

  // Inject HTML
  doc.fromHTML(domElement, 10, 5);

  // Save out to PDF
  doc.save(`${new Date().toISOString()}.pdf`);
};
```

[image]

In fairness I think Ihsan should get the bulk of the credit as this is basically their answer, I just got the content in there by a different means, and positioned the copied HTML.

[image: Edit border-not-aligned-properly-in-pdf-snippet-attached]

Comment: Thanks for your solution with example bro..But the requirement is in this particular pdf page where you have placed the content will be acting as header and for that the content will be different (Might be company logo with company name) ... Whereas the main content which you placed in the top will be after the border line (After the border of header in the top box).. Hope you get my requirement.. I could also provide more details if needed over the requirement..

Comment: In question I have attached a screenshot at last which has the page number at right which will be acting as header in real app, after that section along with border, the main content will be placed..

Comment: @Undefined It's really a simple matter of tweaking the coordinate used when attaching dom element to the doc (`doc.fromHTML(domElement, 10, 5);`), just add more to the y-coordinate to move it down below where the header would occupy. Alternatively you can include the header as part of the JSX you want to send to a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro.. Now I understood the point which you are saying and thanks for your help..

Comment: Hi bro, I have included header and footer here https://codesandbox.io/s/border-not-aligned-properly-in-pdf-snippet-attached-forked-19tlq but this time I am getting error.. Could you help me with the reason for this? I have searched for lot of solutions around but couldn't get the right solution..

Comment: Hi bro, I have included header and footer here https://codesandbox.io/s/border-not-aligned-properly-in-pdf-snippet-attached-forked-19tlq but this time I am getting error.. Could you help me with the reason for this? I have searched for lot of solutions around but couldn't get the right solution..

Comment: Hi @Undefined, I don't know the exact cause, or understand why this happens, but it seems the use alone of the `header` and/or `footer` element(s) is causing this issue. I noticed the DOM is also copied out of order in the resulting PDF. If I place the header content in an `h1` and footer content in a `div` it seems to create PDF without issue. I see you are using an older jsPDF version, and v2 appears to have different html support. I don't have time right now to dig deeper on this, but might later today.

Comment: Thanks for your input bro.. I am totally stuck with this task.. If you could help me with modifying your solution to have header and footer, then that would be much more beneficial for me to proceed.. As you said you can help me sometime later today your time.. Thanks once again..

Comment: @Undefined In spare cycles I've been reading through Github issues and looking at different versions of jsPDF to get around the `header`/`footer` element issue and so far it's not looking too good. It seems the v1.x versions don't handle HTML all that well, but as I said, using an HTML element other than these two appears to keep the DOM in order. When I had a bit more time I was going to explore v2.x if they handle HTML better.

Comment: Okay bro, Thanks for your input.. If you could help me with any different library that will handle heder/footer along with page border then that would also be much more helpful..

Comment: @DrewReese, Could you help me to fix this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66950166/7785337

Answer (score 1):

following to my comment, this is the example you can use to setup you pdf layout. you can try it on online editor

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.setFillColor("#000000")
  doc.rect(5, 5, 200, 0.3)
  doc.rect(5, 5, 0.3, 285)
  doc.rect(5, 290, 200, 0.3)
  doc.rect(5, 30, 200, 0.3)
  doc.rect(205, 5, 0.3, 285)
```

Comment: I have implemented your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/html2canvas-jspdf-forked-40kjj?file=/src/index.js , But it is making the content overlap above the border.. Requirement is the content needs to be inside border.. In the attached screenshot in question, we will have the header placed so there is border from top.. And after that the content needs to be placed..

Comment: in jspdf you have to pay attention to the order, you put my code before your `addImage` method, of course it will be above my code. as for positioning, you have to refer to the documentation https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html

Comment: @IhsanFajarRamadhan, Could you help me to fix this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66950166/7785337